# solaris + change the default shell

Tags: solaris

I have Solaris machine , by default tcsh is the shell

How to change the default shell to bash, 
for example - after log out and login again I will have the bash in place the tcsh!

I mean after log out and log in by ps command I will see bash and not tcsh ,

```
   my_solaris:/ ROOT > ps
   PID TTY         TIME CMD
   13950 pts/4       0:00 ps
   9951 pts/4       0:00 tcsh
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the login shell that has been set for your account with the usermod command.

```
usermod -s /usr/bin/bash diana
```

Double check the path of the bash shell on your machine with `which bash`.

Note that the usermod command requires root privileges.

Comment: Not only double-check, but also run the shell, to make sure that there are no missing dynamic dependencies (which I have experienced). At least do `/usr/bin/bash --version`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `exec` command to execute a program in place of your current shell which terminates. To change your shell to bash you can use

```
exec bash
```

will switch your shell to bash

```
exec tcsh
```

will switch it back again

EDIT:

Now that you have changed your question to mean something different the answers will be different

You will need to have root access to do this but either of the following should work

```
passwd -e diana 
Old Shell: /usr/bin/tcsh
New Shell: /usr/bin/bash
passwd: password information changed for diana
```

or

```
usermod -s /usr/bin/bash diana
```

Comment: see my update - you solution is temp solution , after log out and log in I need to see bash and not tcsh

Comment: You should be able to figure out how to do that yourself it's incredibly basic shell administration.  I've said it before but I'll say it again. You really need to speak to your manager about some very basic unix education.

Comment: @Diana thx lain now your answered on my question , sorry about my confusion question

Comment: @Diana, have you read the message I sent you? don't make things worse by being rude.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

[How to change Solaris shell](http://djcraven5.blogspot.com/2008/03/change-solaris-shell-to-bash.html)

You should read some of the comments they mention important things.

What it looks like you need to do is mess with the environment vars a little in your `~/.profile`

```
setenv SHELL /usr/bin/bash
exec $SHELL
```

then to change it back you just change `SHELL` back to the default value. This works for `csh` and `ksh`. It may even to do this on reboot I am not sure.

As read further into the page, I see someone talking about adding the above commands into a file called `~/.cshrc`

Comment: @Diana Its fixed.

Comment: It appears the user "owns" the machine in question, and shouldn't have to resort to backwards-tactics. An "official" way to change the shell should be possible as root.

Answer (score 1):

For Solaris 11 (and Solaris 10), as root you can do the following

```
[root@server ~]# passwd -e other_user
Old shell: /usr/bin/bash
New shell: /usr/bin/ksh
passwd: password information changed for other_user
[root@server ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was previously noted : `usermod -s /usr/bin/bash USERNAME` ....

You can also change the **default** shell for **new accounts** by using useradd -D

> useradd -D -s /usr/bin/bash

REFERENCE: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1462/useradd-1m.html